# What is the use case of atomFamily in recoil?

Tags: recoiljs

I did my first experiment with recoil, building an editable table. Each cell has an atom which stores its row, column, and text value.
The way I built this was by

1. initializing each cell's atom into a dictionary (just a plain object), with keys in a format of [column]x[row]
2. I then iterate over these keys in the Table component, and pass only the key to each Cell component
3. The Cell component uses `useRecoilState` and find its specific Atom by accessing the main dictionary using the key it got passed as a prop.

Now, it seems to me that this use case (creating thousands of related atoms with the same shape) is what `atomFamily` is meant to make easier, but I don't understand how to use it in this way, where you initialize each atom with a specific value.

And, besides that, I don't understand what is the advantage of using atomFamily over storing a collection of atoms. I understand there is memoization involved, but I don't understand what is getting memoized other than, if I am reading correctly, the ability to recall a specific atom by calling the function again with the same id, which would get you pretty much the same behavior I'm getting with a dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is very little difference: if you want to manually memoize and manage your own collection of `atom`s, then you certainly can. `atomFamily` is essentially just [sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for that: it handles the [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) for you, so all that you have to do is use a unique key to access each `atom`. Verbatim from [the documentation for `atomFamily`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/utils/atomFamily):

> An `atom` represents a piece of state with *Recoil*. An atom is created and registered per `<RecoilRoot>` by your app. But, what if your state isn’t global? What if your state is associated with a particular instance of a control, or with a particular element? For example, maybe your app is a UI prototyping tool where the user can dynamically add elements and each element has state, such as its position. Ideally, each element would get its own atom of state. You could implement this yourself via a memoization pattern. But, *Recoil* provides this pattern for you with the `atomFamily()` utility. An Atom Family represents a collection of atoms. When you call `atomFamily()` it will return a function which provides the `RecoilState` atom based on the parameters you pass in.

---

As far as examples for how to use `atomFamily`: beyond the documentation linked above, there are [lots of existing questions and answers on Stack Overflow which already cover exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brecoiljs%5D+atomfamily). Here are a couple which I have answered previously:

- [Dynamic atom keys in Recoil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71530571/438273)
- [Looking for a pattern to normalize state in Recoil without losing the benefit of Suspense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71371797/438273)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could you point me to an example in which atoms in an atom family are initialized to specific values?

Comment: @PabloBarríaUrenda The [first answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71530571/438273) that I shared demonstrates how to initialize atoms in an `atomFamily` with dynamically specified values.